# A counterexample of a theorem about matching extendable

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

$M$ is perfect if $M$ covers all vertices of $G$, and $M$ is **extendable** if $G$ has a perfect matching containing $M$. Moreover, a graph $G$ with at least $2k + 2$ vertices is said to be $k$-extendable if any matching $M$ in $G$ with $|M| = k$ is **extendable**.

I read **Plummer's Theorem** from the following paper.

> M.D. Plummer. On n-extendable graphs[J].Discrete Mathematics, 1980, 31(2):201–210.

**Theorem** *Let $k$ be a positive integer. If $G$ is an $k$-extendable graph on  $n\ge 2k+2$ vertices, $G$ is $(k + 1)$-connected.*

I feel like all even cycles $C_n$ for $n\ge 8$ are counter examples. $C_n$ is $\frac{n}{2}$ extendable, but its connectivity is always $2$. The connectivity of $C_n$ is not greater than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}+1(\ge5)$ like the theorem says.
What did I get wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $n\ge2k+2$ in yhour counterexample?

Comment: @bof I see, my counterexample is not correct. (*￣︶￣).